# javascript add number to end on css class with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, forms

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I am looking to make a form input conditionally required. I figured out how to do this, but I also would like there to be some indicator on the text to show it is required.

Not Required: field

Required: **field***

What i have will work if I only do this to one field, but I need to do this to two fields.

#### What I want:

**Field 1***: Val

**Field 2***: Val 2

#### What I get:

**Field 1***: Val

**Field 1***: Val 2

Javascript Code:

```
function Check() {

var value = ($("select[title='Bid']").val());
var asterisk = "*".fontcolor("red");
var maxRequired = $('.more-required').length

if(value == "Yes"){

$('.more-options').show();

    for (i = 0; i <= maxRequired; i++){
        $('.more-required').replaceWith($('.more-required').html() + asterisk);
    }
}else{

$('.more-options').hide();


};  
};
```

Form Code:

```
<tr class="more-options">
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader more-required">
                            <nobr>Assigned To</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff12{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Assigned_x0020_To0" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff12',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Assigned_x0020_To0')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff12description{$Pos}" FieldName="Assigned_x0020_To0" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="more-options">
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader more-required">
                            <nobr>Category</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff13{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Category" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff13',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Category')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff13description{$Pos}" FieldName="Category" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Using the class: *more-required* to get and set the value.

What it does is select the html in the more-required class then adds an asterisk.
When it replaces the title it will only use the title of the first form item with the class. I need it to find the title of each form element then set that with the asterisk.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.replaceWith` function, you are doing `$('.more-required').html()`. `.html` will return the html of the first element in the stack, so *"Field 1"* in your case.

You can use a function inside `.replaceWith` and benefit from the `this` keyword :

```
$('.more-required').replaceWith(function(){
    return $(this).html() + asterisk;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below javascript

```
$('.more-required').each(function (index, elem) {
    $(elem).replaceWith($(elem).html() + asterisk);
});
```

If this doesn't work please provide HTML output as it is hard to predict what HTML will be generated by SharePoint.